# Nested GraphQL query to show latests blog posts in React / GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, graphql, headless, prismic.io

I'm building a website in Gatsby / React with 2 content types: **Pages** and **posts** and query my data via GraphQL (in Prismic).

I want to include a "Recent news"-module on the page, showing the latests blogposts.

**My question is the following:**

> Is there a way to access the data directly in my module, without
> passing the data through every parent React component?

I'm using Prismic in this case, but the same scenario could apply to Contentful, Sanity or any other headless CMS I guess.

This is how I query my data:

```
query pageQuery($uid: String, $lang: String) {
    prismic {
      allPages(uid: $uid, lang: $lang) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            heading
            body {
              ... on PRISMIC_PageBodyNews {
                type
                primary {
                  news_heading
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      allRecentPosts: allPosts(first: 2) {
        edges {
          node {
            publish_date
            title
            _meta {
              uid
              lang
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What I was looking for a way to achieve:

```
query pageQuery($uid: String, $lang: String) {
    prismic {
      allPages(uid: $uid, lang: $lang) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            heading
            body {
              ... on PRISMIC_PageBodyNews {
                type
                primary {
                  news_heading
                }
                allRecentPosts: allPosts(first: 2) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      publish_date
                      title
                      _meta {
                        uid
                        lang
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Right now I'm getting the following error:
`error  Cannot query field "allPosts" on type "PRISMIC_PageBodyNews"  graphql/template-string` which makes sense, since `allPosts` is not allowed in the current schema.

However, before I try changing my schema I want to hear if it's even possible to define my schema in a way that allows "sub-queries" in GraphQL / Prismic this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add root `query` field or a `prismic` field as a field of some objecttypes. But I don't think that Prismic supports this.

It is better to use fragments and/or several graphql queries. Depending on your graphql client and caching policy it can still trigger only one roundtrip to your server.

Also you can just use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to pass data to a deep nested component.

If you really need to have nested queries then take a look at [graphql-compose](https://graphql-compose.github.io/docs/basics/understanding-types.html#object-types-via-objecttypecomposer). It supports callback as a field type definition. So it should not have troubles with type loops and self-referencing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `useContext` is probably the way to go. Just wanted to make sure there weren't some easy way to nest it instead. Getting nested queries to work will probably take much longer than just going with `useContext`